# How can i load the strategy map using spring and annotations?

Tags: java, spring, strategy-pattern

I'm implementing the strategy pattern using spring and to Load the correct strategy implementation, follow this example:

```
public class ShippingServiceImpl implements ShippingService {
 // Map of strategies
 private Map<ShippingType,ShippingCostStrategy> shippingCostStrategies;

 @Required
 public void setShippingCostStrategies(Map<ShippingType,ShippingCostStrategy> strategies) {
  this.shippingCostStrategies = strategies;
 }

 @Override
 public BigDecimal calculateShippingCost(ShoppingCart cart) {
  return shippingCostStrategies.get(cart.getShippingType()).shippingCost(cart);
 }

 // ...other business logic...
}
```

How is the best way to Load this strategy Map? I want a specific method that loads the map and pass to setShippingCostStrategies ? Can i do it using spring Annotations? because in this example, the author do it using configuration:

```
<bean id="shippingService"        class="it.nicus.springstrategy.ShippingServiceImpl">
 <property name="shippingCostStrategies">
  <map>
   <entry>
    <key><util:constant  static-  field="it.nicus.springstrategy.ShippingType.NORMAL"/></key>
    <bean class="it.nicus.springstrategy.PerItemCostStrategyImpl">
     <property name="baseCost" value="5.00"/>
     <property name="costPerItem" value="2.00"/>
    </bean>
   </entry>
   <entry>
    <key><util:constant  static-  field="it.nicus.springstrategy.ShippingType.PRIME"/></key>
    <bean class="it.nicus.springstrategy.FixedCostStrategyImpl">
     <property name="fixedCost" value="3.00" />
    </bean>
   </entry>
  </map>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register the `map` as bean using [`<util:map>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-map) tag, and then use `@Resource` annotation to autowire that map.

```html
<util:map id="strategyMap">
    <entry>
        <key>
            <util:constant static-field="it.nicus.springstrategy.ShippingType.NORMAL" />
        </key>
        <bean class="it.nicus.springstrategy.PerItemCostStrategyImpl">
            <property name="baseCost" value="5.00" />
            <property name="costPerItem" value="2.00" />
        </bean>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>
            <util:constant static-field="it.nicus.springstrategy.ShippingType.PRIME" />
        </key>
        <bean class="it.nicus.springstrategy.FixedCostStrategyImpl">
            <property name="fixedCost" value="3.00" />
        </bean>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

And then, in `ShippingServiceImpl` class, inject it like this:

```
public class ShippingServiceImpl implements ShippingService {
   // Map of strategies
    @Resource(name="strategyMap")
    private Map<ShippingType,ShippingCostStrategy> shippingCostStrategies;
}
```

Comment: thanks !! What is the advantage related to create an factory?

Comment: @Mr.PaulHenry Sorry, I didn't understand?

Comment: For example, instead to load into Map, all strategies, Can i create an factory that inspects the parameter using if conditional and return the correct implementation? is this approach poor , related to that one?

Comment: Strategy and Factory are two completely different categories of patterns. Former being the operational pattern, and later being the creational pattern. It completely depends upon your use-case, what you want to do, depending upon that, you can choose one of them. I suggest going through wikipedia pages for both the patterns to get an idea

Comment: Ok, i know that.. the factory pattern will replace the part of fill the map using strategies... for example: ShippingConstFactory and inside that, i will inject the strategies, and make some IF conditionals to choose between the right implementation....i don't know if i clear now . thanks !!